# javascript - object templating

Tags: javascript, new-operator

In my script, i'm trying to create an object from some template. so i've created a function which returns and object.

What actually happens when I use the a,b,c calls?

```
function newO(){
  return {
    "key": "value"
  };
}
// call a
var x = new newO();
// call b
var x = new newO;
// call c
var x = newO();
```

Comment: All three will return an object with a key (``.key``) of "value" due to being a constructor.

Comment: Why not try yourself?

Comment: @el.pescado i did, and i ask for an explanation